# How to compare external password with DotNetNuke encrypted one?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I have a DotNetNuke database and an independent C# webservice. I receive two strings from the webservice, a "user code", that allows me to identify the user, and its password. I need to compare that password with the DotNetNuke one, but I can't find how to do it. How should I encrypt the password in order to compare it? I already have the DotNetNuke aspnet_membership registry which I need to compare with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: the password can be stored with one of the following passwordFormat (set in the web.config): "Clear", "Hashed" (it uses SHA1) and "Encrypted" (Triple-DES).

Answer (score 0):

The DotNetNuke stored password will be Hashed, using a different hashing algorithm dependant on your setup.

If you find out what hash you are using, you could replicate the hashing on your passwords, and compare the results.

Comment: the passwordFormat is set to "Encrypted" not to "Hashed"

Comment: In that case why not just encrypt whatever is sent to you and compare it?

Comment: What I couldn't find was the encryption method, but I found it, it is triple-des. I have not answer my own question because I can't do it during the next 8 hours after publishing a question